# Addon preferences don't show consistently

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on, customization

### Background

I have some add-on preferences in the modular tree add-on I have been contributing to.

### Problem

They show up fine on my macbook with blender 2.77, but they appear to be missing on windows and linux computers using the same blender version. Any ideas as to why?

### Extra Info

I have personally tested it on a windows 7 box: there are no errors and all the functionality works fine (so the add-on prefs *are* registering correctly). It is just impossible to change the add-on prefs without a knowledge of scripting because it doesn't show up in blender's UI.

Github repo:

https://github.com/MaximeHerpin/modular_tree

Blender Artists thread:

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?405377-Addon-Modular-Tree&p=3101211#post3101211

What it *should* look like (the rest don't show anything past the "Internet: <kbd>Docs</kbd>  <kbd>Report</kbd>  <kbd>Remove</kbd>" line):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install the add-on from the zip provided by GitHub, Blender unpacks the zip's contents, a folder called `modular_tree-master`, into Blender's local add-on storage folder (the exact location varies between operating systems). The main point is that the add-on folder is no longer `modular_tree`, that's also the problem.

There's an assumption in this section of the code.

```
class TreeAddonPrefs(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = "modular_tree"
```

Hardcoding `bl_idname` like that assumes that the folder name (*or "package name"*) is still  "modular_tree".

There are many solutions, some more convoluted than others..

#### 0. Renaming the content of the zip.

*(don't do this, only included for completeness).*

You can rename the folder inside the zip to simply `modular_tree` (using something like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html)) before installing, it will display the add-on preferences correctly. But doing that is kind of a hassle, most of your users will need to do it if they aren't getting your add-on as a GIT project.  you should be fixing it in one place for everyone.

#### 1. "Monkey Patching" the `__package__` name

One way to force the package name is:

```
# somewhere at the start of your __init__
if __name__ != "modular_tree":
    sys.modules["modular_tree"] = sys.modules[__name__]
```

then you can do

```
class TreeAddonPrefs(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __package__
```

#### 2. using basename and dirname of `__file__`

```
# somewhere at the top of your __init__.py
from os.path import basename, dirname
```

then

```
class TreeAddonPrefs(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = basename(dirname(__file__))  # directory name containing this file
```

---

The result is that it doesn't matter what the zip was called / or the eventual folder.

Comment: I am actually one of the developers as I mentioned :) The problem is that I can't use __name__ because it is a multi-file add-on...I have not yet tried what you mentioned, but it sounds right so I'll accept your answer. I actually made the add-on preferences code that you cited, and I thought that the bl_idname for the add-on prefs would actually set the idname instead of require an existing idname.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I actually already made a hot fix for the project by adding an "addon_name" module to handle this. (It saves a text file with the name it decides on for reference from other modules.) I will look into using your idea as well.